# Getting regression coefficients for all list elements without using a loop

Tags: r, regression

Given two lists with identical keys, can you get regression coefficients into a third list *without using loops and hopefully also without creating temporary data frames for each list item*?

I'm familiar with `lapply`, but don't know how to apply it for this case, if that's even possible!

```
s = list()
s$x = list(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(4, 5, 6))
s$y = list(a=c(1, 2, 4), b=c(4, 5, 8))

for(i in names(s$x)) {
  df = data.frame(x = s$x[[i]], y = s$y[[i]])
  model = lm(y ~ x, df)
  s$co[[i]] = model$coefficients
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the indicated anonymous function over x and y extracting the coefficients and concatenate that to the input s.  No packages are used.

```
s_out <- c(s, co = list(Map(function(x, y) coef(lm(y ~ x)), s$x, s$y)))
```

giving:

```
> str(s_out)
List of 3
 $ x :List of 2
  ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ b: num [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ y :List of 2
  ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 4
  ..$ b: num [1:3] 4 5 8
 $ co:List of 2
  ..$ a: Named num [1:2] -0.667 1.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
  ..$ b: Named num [1:2] -4.33 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
```

Comment: This is my personal favourite so far. It's short, easy to read, and uses no packages.

Answer (score 4):

#### One liner solution

```
library(purrr)
s1 <- c(s, map2(s$x, s$y, ~lm(.y ~ .x)$co))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would be useful

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(s))[, coef(lm(value[L1=="y"]~value[L1=="x"])) , L2]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
s %>%
   transpose %>%
   map(~coef(lm(.[["y"]] ~ .[["x"]]))) %>%
   c(s, co = .)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using `lapply()` and `base r`.

```
s = list()
s$x = list(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(4, 5, 6))
s$y = list(a=c(1, 2, 4), b=c(4, 5, 8))

coeff.list <- lapply(names(s$x), (function(i){
  df = data.frame(x = s$x[[i]], y = s$y[[i]])
  model = lm(y ~ x, df)
  model$coefficients
}))
names(coeff.list) <- names(s$x)

coeff.list
```